# Unexpected results in linked list code in java

Tags: java

Following code compiles and executes without any errors or warnings. But gives an unexpected result.

Code :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

//defining a custom data-type (class)
class LLObj{
    static int NodeInt;
    static char NodeChar;

    LLObj(int x, char y){
        NodeInt = x;
        NodeChar = y;
    }
}

class LLexp{

    static LinkedList<LLObj> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        list.addLast(new LLObj(5,'c'));

        System.out.println(list.get(0).NodeInt);
        System.out.println(list.get(0).NodeChar);

        list.addLast(new LLObj(7,'h'));

        System.out.println(list.get(0).NodeInt);
        System.out.println(list.get(0).NodeChar);
        System.out.println(list.get(1).NodeInt);
        System.out.println(list.get(1).NodeChar);
    }
}
```

Expected Output -

> 5
>   c
>   5
>   c
>   7
>   h

Obtained Output -

> 5
>   c
>   7
>   h
>   7
>   h

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I get the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
static int NodeInt;
static char NodeChar;
```

If the intention is for each `LLObj` to have its own values (which seems likely), these should be *instance* variables.

It's very important to understand the difference between instance fields/methods and static fields/methods. See the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined NodeInt and NodeChar as static variables. Static variables are at class level and doesn't hold different values for different instances.
Remove static from both and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
//defining a custom data-type (class)
class LLObj
{
    static int NodeInt;
    static char NodeChar;

    LLObj(int x, char y)
    {
        NodeInt = x;
        NodeChar = y;
    }
}
```

All objects you create from LLObj class **share** the same data members,

**Static data members are associated with the Class, not an initiated object,**

And with your example, the value of NodeInt and NodeChar for all objects created from LLObj will be the initial values of the last object created ..